# What is PRIu64 in C?

Tags: c, macros, printf

I am new to C and I am confronted with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t foo = 10;
    printf("foo is equal to %" PRIu64 "!\n", foo);
    
    return 0;
}
```

And it works! I don't understand why. Can somebody help me about this?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

[`PRIu64`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) is a format specifier, introduced in C99, for printing `uint64_t`, where `uint64_t` is (from linked reference page):

> unsigned integer type with width of ... 64 bits respectively
>   (provided only if the implementation directly supports the type)

`PRIu64` is a string (literal), for example the following:

```
printf("%s\n", PRIu64);
```

prints `llu` on my machine. Adjacent string literals are concatenated, from section *6.4.5 String literals* of the C99 standard:

> In translation phase 6, **the multibyte character sequences specified by any sequence of adjacent character and wide string literal tokens are concatenated into a single multibyte character sequence**. If any of the tokens are wide string literal tokens, the resulting multibyte character sequence is treated as a wide string literal; otherwise, it is treated as a character string literal.

This means:

```
printf("foo is equal to %" PRIu64 "!\n", foo);
```

(on my machine) is the same as:

```
printf("foo is equal to %llu!\n", foo);
```

See http://ideone.com/jFvKR9 .

Comment: @torr It depends upon the choices made by your hardware, OS, compiler and library (collectively called "the implementation") as to whether or not `PRIu64` expands to `"llu"`. On some implementations it may expand to `"u"`, instead, meaning that `"%u"` would be appropriate for printing `uint64_t` values. That shouldn't be relied upon, however. There are no other *portable* ways to print `uint64_t` values that you'd be happy with.