# Is there a proper formatter for boost::uint64_t to use with snprintf?

Tags: c++, boost, string-formatting

I am using `boost/cstdint.hpp` in a C++ project because I am compiling in C++03 mode (`-std=c++03`) and I want to have fixed-width integers (they are transmitted over the network and stored to files). I am also using `snprintf` because it is a *simple* and *fast* way to format strings.

Is there a proper formatter to use `boost::uint64_t` with `snprintf(...)` or should I switch to another solution ([boost::format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/format/), std::ostringstream) ?

I am current using `%lu` but I am not fully happy with it as it may not work on another architecture (where `boost::uint64_t` is not defined as `long unsigned`), defeating the purpose of using fixed-width integers.

```
boost::uint64_t id
id = get_file_id(...)
const char* ENCODED_FILENAME_FORMAT = "encoded%lu.dat";
//...
char encoded_filename[34];
snprintf(encoded_filename, 34, ENCODED_FILENAME_FORMAT, id);
```

Answer (score 3):

`snprintf` isn't a Boost function. It knows how to print the fundamental types only. If none of those coincides with `boost::uint64_t`, then it isn't even possible to print that.

In general, as you note the formatter has to match the underlying type. So even if it's possible, the formatter will be platform-dependent. There's no extension mechanism by which Boost can add new formatters to `snprintf`.

Comment: In C++11 or C99, you have the header `<inttypes.h>` which defines the macro `PRIu64` , the proper formatter for a `uint64_t` . I was hoping boost would provide a similar mechanism. And a 64 bits unsigned integer is kindof a fundamental type. Please see this SO post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859500/mmh-who-are-you-priu64

Comment: @Xion345: That's a macro from the standard library applying to the same standard library. That's a lot easier.

Comment: Ok, I see your point now. I was thinking boost could provide this type of mechanism as `uint64_t` is an alias for `unsigned`, `long unsigned` or `long long unsigned` on most platforms (so formatters for these types exist). So in addition to providing the proper alias for `uint64_t`, boost could also provide the proper alias for `PRIu64` (whether it is `%u`, `%lu`, `%llu`).