# C - timeval to uint64_t

Tags: c, timeval

Morning!

I'm trying to get a nanosecond timestamp (uint64_t) from a timeval struct.

```
    struct timeval t;
    // initialized so that ....
    print("t sec: %ld, micro sec: %ld", t.tv_sec, t.tv_usec);
    // .... prints "t sec: 4, micro sec: 130728"

    long int sec = (long int) t.tv_sec;
    // just did that because I thought that using time_t in calculations may cause errors
    // print("%ld", sec) -> 4, so this seems to work as expected    

    uint64_t t_int = (sec * 1000000 + t.tv_usec) * 1000; // should be nanoseconds
    print("t_int (uint64_t) %llu", t_int);
    // prints "t_int (uint64_t) 18446744073545312320"
```

My timevals should definitely fit into uint64_t. Also, the cast to long int from time_t works, so all I'm doing is a simple calculation with two long ints, putting the result into a uint64_t, so I'm not sure why I'm getting an obviously wrong value. Any ideas? Is this just a wrong way of formatting (with %llu)?

Comment: What size is `long int` on your machine? What value do you get for `sec`? Are you aware that your calculation `sec * 1000000` is done using `long int`, not `uint64_t`? As well as all other calculations in that snippet.

Comment: `printf("t_int (uint64_t) %"PRIu64,t_int);`  code  with the correct formatter for uint64_t. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859500/mmh-who-are-you-priu64).

Answer (score 3):

Either:

```
uint64_t t_int = ((uint64_t)t.tv_sec * 1000000 + t.tv_usec) * 1000;
```

or:

```
uint64_t t_int = (t.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + t.tv_usec) * 1000;
```

The latter skips the cast and instead performs the promotion by having the right-hand operand of the `*` already be a type that's at least 64-bit (instead of casting the left-hand side up to one). Either works; it's a matter of what style you prefer.

Do not go through a temp var of type `long` like you did. `long` may be a 32-bit type and will not fit times past January 2038. If you need a temp var, make it `time_t` or `int64_t` or similar. But it's not needed.

Also you may want to consider using `int64_t` (and changing the `ULL` to `LL`) instead of `uint64_t`, so that you can represent times before 1970.

Comment: "consider using `int64_t`" is a good idea as  [specified](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/systypes.h.html) `.tv_usec` and certainly `.tv_sec` are signed quantities.

Comment: Thanks, worked flawlessly. I'll keep it unsigned though, since I'm using this to just count time from a start to a stop time.

Answer (score 2):

You are calculating with `long int` width. Because it overflows undefined behavior happens and some negative value is assigned to `uint64_t` which results in a big positive value (on your architecture). Calculate with `uint64_t` or `unsigned long long` precision. To be pedantic, cast all values:

```
uint64_t t_int = ((uint64_t)sec * 1000000ull + (uint64_t)t.tv_usec) * 1000ull;
```

But because of promotions most probably just casting one value to `uint64_t` is enough:

```
uint64_t t_int = ((uint64_t)sec * 1000000 + t.tv_usec) * 1000;
```

Comment: Even storing `long int sec = (long int) t.tv_sec;` to begin with is a bug. It will overflow Y2038 on implementations with 32-bit long. Instead you want to just use `t.tv_sec` directly, or make the useless temp var `sec` have type `time_t` if you insist on having it.