# Why on Linux is uint64_t defined as unsigned long int, while on Windows it is unsigned long long int?

Tags: c, linux, uint64

I need to use `uint64_t` as `unsigned long long int` due to the fact that I need to fit in numbers larger than `unsigned long` in it? (both OSes are 64-bit), how can I fix this? Here is the code which impleements binary division:
Here is the function where I tried to print to see the result of the final function:

```
void binary_div(s21_big_decimal *value_1, s21_big_decimal value_2, s21_big_decimal *result) {
  init_s21_decimal(result);
  s21_big_decimal Q;
  s21_big_decimal R;
  int scaleDiv = -1;
  do {
    init_s21_decimal(&R);
    init_s21_decimal(&Q);
    scaleDiv++;
    int lastBit = (SIZE_BIG_DECIMAL - 1) * 32 - 1;
    int currentBit = get_bit_big(*value_1, lastBit);
    while (currentBit == 0 && lastBit >= 0) {
      currentBit = get_bit_big(*value_1, lastBit);
      if (currentBit == 0) lastBit--;
    }
    for (int i = lastBit; i >= 0; i--) {
      change_left_big(&R, 1);
      set_bit_big(&R, 0, get_bit_big(*value_1, i));
      if (is_less_or_equal_big(value_2, R)) {
        s21_big_decimal res = {0};
        init_s21_decimal(&res);
        s21_sub_big(R, value_2, &res);
        init_s21_decimal(&R);
        copy_bits(res, &R);
        set_bit_big(&Q, i, 1);
      }
    }
    if (scaleDiv > 0) {
      mul_10_big(result);
    }
    s21_big_decimal res;
    init_s21_decimal(&res);
    add_big(*result, Q, &res);
    copy_bits(res, result);
    if (!is_zero_big(R)) {
      init_s21_decimal(value_1);
      mul_10_big(&R);
      copy_bits(R, value_1);
    }
  } while (!is_zero_big(R) && scaleDiv < 28);
  set_scale_big(result, scaleDiv);
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    printf("%lX ", result->bits[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

I work with bits here is example of the function mul_10_big:

```c
int mul_10_big(s21_big_decimal *dec)
{
  s21_big_decimal temp = *dec;
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_BIG_DECIMAL - 1; i++)
  {
    temp.bits[i] *= 10;
  }
  temp.scale++;
  int overflowed = 0;
  if (getoverflow(&temp))
  {
    overflowed = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    *dec = temp;
  }
  return overflowed;
}
int div_10_big(s21_big_decimal *dec)
{
  uint64_t remained = 0;
  for (int i = SIZE_BIG_DECIMAL - 2; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    dec->bits[i] += remained << 32;
    remained = dec->bits[i] % 10;
    dec->bits[i] /= 10;
  }
  dec->scale--;
  return remained;
}
int add_big(s21_big_decimal big_dec1, s21_big_decimal big_dec2,
            s21_big_decimal *result)
{
  int res = 0;
  normalization_big(&big_dec1, &big_dec2);
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_BIG_DECIMAL - 1; i++)
  {
    result->bits[i] += big_dec1.bits[i] + big_dec2.bits[i];
    getoverflow(result);
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: If you need a `uint64_t`, then just use that.

Comment: `uint64_t` is a 64 bit long unsigned integer regardless of the platform. So I am not sure what you are asking for.

Comment: Can you please post the code that you have, and explain what you want to do and what doesn't work?

Comment: @gulpr: `unsigned long long` always has at least 64 bits, even on non-64 bit platforms, and I'm not aware of any platform where it has more.

Comment: @NateEldredge The code is large, but here is an example : I have an array `uint64_t bits[SIZE_BIG];` and when I print it on Windows it is `60000000 7948AECA D269AE4A 6B41DD10 64209812 293E346 380000` so and also I print it as %llx, but on Linux this number is too large and also I printed it %llx, but the system said that I should print uint64_t as %lx so on linux uint64_t aka unsigned long it

Comment: @olya [you have to use `PRIu64` to print `uint64_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16859500/995714). Using the wrong format specifier invokes UB

Comment: @phuclv The problem is not in printing, I print just to firgure out th problem, I multiplicate large numbers so when I printed it on different OS I saw that on linux uint64_t is unsigned long int

Comment: **Please show us actual code.** Your short comments are too vague to understand what is going on.  It doesn't have to be your entire large program; you should be able to strip it down to a self-contained program of a few lines that shows the issue (a [mcve]).

Comment: @olya instead of describing your code like in _"I have an array uint64_t bits[SIZE_BIG]; and when I print it on Windows it is 60000000 ...."_, [edit] the question and post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem along with expected and actual output on on both Linux and Windows.

Comment: A [mcve] means something that somebody could compile, run, and test.  It needs all types defined, all headers included, etc.  Any other code not relevant to reproducing the problem should be removed or stubbed out.  The most glaring problem with what you've posted is that we don't have the definition of the type `s21_big_decimal`, and you haven't explained what actually goes wrong with the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 5):

`uint64_t` is `unsigned long` on linux and macOS because the type `unsigned long` has 64 bits so there is no need to use a type with a larger rank such as `unsigned long long` eventhough this later type also has 64 bits.

On Windows, `uint64_t` cannot be typedefed to `unsigned long` because for legacy reasons, Microsoft chose to keep `unsigned long` as a 32-bit type even on its 64-bit ABIs.

If you need to handle numbers larger than `4294967295`, you should indeed not use `unsigned long` that may be limited to 32 bits.  Using `uint64_t` that has exactly 64 bits or `unsigned long long` that has at least 64 bits are the correct choices. `uint64_t` might not be available on all platforms, but is on your targets and you are unlikely to ever encounter one that does not.

Whether `uint64_t` is typedefed to `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` does not matter for your purpose as it always has 64 bits.

Changing the type `uint64_t` is not an option as you will get potential undefined behavior using different definitions in different modules.

If you use integer types consistently in your application, using `uint64_t` everywhere you need a 64-bit unsigned type should not pose a problem.

For reading and printing, you can either use the standard macros defined in `<inttypes.h>`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    uint64_t x;
    if (argc > 1 && sscanf(argv[1], "%"SCNu64"", &x) == 1) {
        printf("%16"PRIx64"\n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you prefer, you can use `strtoull` and `printf` this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buf[100];
    uint64_t x;
    if (argc > 1) {
        x = strtoul(argv[1], NULL, 10);
        printf("%16llx"\n", (unsigned long long)x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You could also define your own type `u64_t` as a typedef for `unsigned long long` and use `%llu` or `%llx` in `scanf` and `printf` like functions without extra casts.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned long long u64_t;  // assuming 64-bit

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    u64_t x;
    if (argc > 1 && sscanf(argv[1], "%llu", &x) == 1) {
        printf("%16llx\n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or you can simply use `unsigned long long` everywhere.

Comment: *for legacy reasons, Microsoft chose...* Microsoft kept `long` as 32 bits because they **could**.  Unix systems went to 64 bits well before `long long` was standardized in C99 and well nigh a full two decades before `long long` was standardized for C++ - which didn't happen until C++11.  When SGI's Irix went to 64 bits in 1991 `long long` probably didn't even exist.  Microsoft was able to keep `long` at 32 bits because they were so late to the 64 bit party.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I agree with you, Microsoft came very late to the 64-bit party and could have chosen the ABI already used by other players, but they instead **chose** to keep `long` as 32 bits because changing that would have made porting WIN32 software to WIN64 more difficult (*legacy reasons*).  They had to typedef `size_t` to `unsigned long long`, which makes `sizeof(size_t) > sizeof(long)`, yet did not support the `z` and `t` conversion length specifiers for another 10 or so years...