# How to return a 16 bit value as 64 bit?

Tags: c, 64-bit, printf

```
// Returns 64 bit mac timer count value
uint64_t get_timestamp()
{
    uint16_t cnt;
    cnt =   read_counter(); 
    printk ("counter value is 0x%x\n", cnt);
    return cnt;
}
```

within caller:

```
uint64_t ts;        
ts =    get_timestamp();
printk ( "returned timestamp is 0x%x \n", ts );
```

I got the following on screen, What is wrong above?

counter value is `0x000045a5`
returned timestamp is `0x00000000`

counter value is `0x0000698f`
returned timestamp is `0x00000000`

Comment: I think you need a different format specifier for 64 bit integers, not just `%x`. See [What is the argument for printf that formats a long?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561/what-is-the-argument-for-printf-that-formats-a-long). But don't ask me if `%lx`, `%llx`, `%l64x` or whatever is correct.

Comment: the problem is with the format. Values will be implicitly cast to the correct type so in most cases you don't need to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this issue becasuse you print out the values incorrectly.
there are dedicated `printf` format macros for the `uint*_t` types.

from the manpage of `<inttypes.h>`:

```
   The fprintf() macros for signed integers are:


          PRIdN        PRIdLEASTN   PRIdFASTN    PRIdMAX      PRIdPTR
          PRIiN        PRIiLEASTN   PRIiFASTN    PRIiMAX      PRIiPTR

   The fprintf() macros for unsigned integers are:


          PRIoN        PRIoLEASTN   PRIoFASTN    PRIoMAX      PRIoPTR
          PRIuN        PRIuLEASTN   PRIuFASTN    PRIuMAX      PRIuPTR
          PRIxN        PRIxLEASTN   PRIxFASTN    PRIxMAX      PRIxPTR
          PRIXN        PRIXLEASTN   PRIXFASTN    PRIXMAX      PRIXPTR
```

so for example, to print a `uint16_t` and a `uint64_t` you could write (untested):

```
int main (void)
{
  uint16_t a = 13;
  uint64_t b = 37;

  printf("uint16_t: %" PRIx16 ", uint64_t: %" PRIx64 "\n", a, b);

  return 0;
}
```

you should read `man stdint.h` and `man inttypes.h` if you are interested in the details, and what the semantics of the `LEAST` and `FAST` types are. very cool stuff.