# assign negatives to char* using sprintf

Tags: c, printf, signed

I have a line in my program that goes like: `sprintf (line, "%s [%lu..%lu]", pp->help, min, max);` where `min, max;` are `unsigned long` and `line` is `char[SOME_SIZE]`. Before the `sprintf` is invoked I call a function that can assign negatives to `min` and min gets the value of `-5` which translates to `4294967291` because it's unsigned.

So I tried to do something like:

```
if((long)min < 0) // works fine because 4294967291 has the binary of 0x1...
    sprintf (line, "%s [%d..%d]", pp->help, (long)min, max);
```

but that does not work. The if is true, but I still get positive numbers (i.e. `4294967291`) when I print line, how can I fix this?

*NOTE:* I'm not sure how the print is implemented in the end of the execution but right now the `sprintf` itself is not working as i want it to, as it adds unsigned to the string instead of signed.

this is a simplification of my code:

```
unsigned long min = foo() /* in this case -5 */, max = goo() /* in this case 5*/;
char line[100];

if((long)min < 0){
    sprintf (line, "%s [%d..%d]", pp->help, (long)min, max);
}// when it prints I get [4294967291..5] instead of [-5..5]
else{
    sprintf (line, "%s [%lu..%lu]", pp->help, min, max);
}
```

**EDIT:** I tried to get similar results on my gcc but failed. But I saw something very strange that could explain this. When `line` is declared, it is `char[]`, but when the debugger reaches the `sprintf`, `line` is identified as `unsigned char`... but sadly I can't post the code here.

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what output you expect for what values.

Comment: 1) Any reason you use an `unsigned long` although you want a `signed long` apparently? 2) Provide a [mcve]. 3) Sounds like an XY problem (see 1) 4) The conversion unsigned to signed is implementation defined. Which behaviour does your implementation specify?

Comment: @Olaf 1) I'm just doing a workaround, I don't want to change the whole function (somewhat big function)  2)I edited my q  3) I edited my q   4) 2's complement is the method used here

Comment: Cannot reproduce, click here -> [this](http://ideone.com/uB9u9i) works for me.

Comment: Please edit-in exactly what you are getting (not "that does not work") and what you are expecting (_concrete values) as that can provide clues as to what's wrong. For example, depending on your compiler/platform, you _might_ need `%ld` for the signed output. Seeing what gets printed for `max` (and what it should be) may help in deciding that.

Comment: And [this](http://ideone.com/Aadf7h) works also for me.

Comment: '%l' is the right format string for a signed long, not '%d'. Maybe that causes the problem

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt I'm checking this right now, but with "%ld". is there a difference? I couldn't tell from what I read in the internet

Comment: my fault, %ld is correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the argument for printf that formats a long?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561/what-is-the-argument-for-printf-that-formats-a-long)

Comment: Not wanting to refactor a function is a very bad reason to use a cast! If this is production code and you have a good project supervisor, you will run into trouble with that excuse. And 2's complement is an encoding for negative values, not a conversion method!

Comment: @Olaf if this would be my last hope, then of course I'll change the existing code, but I want to do as little as possible in order to not mess up with legacy code. I now think of converting it first to a string, adjusting it and then adding to original string

Comment: And what would that change about the conversion issue? With all due respect, but there seem to be some basics missing.