# main.c:12:25: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’,

Tags: c++, c, printf

I'm getting this error when trying to compile my code...

```c
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
void powRec(long int firstrNum, long int secondNum)
{
    int n;
    if (secondNum == 1)
        ;
    {
        printf("The result is %ld", firstrNum);
        return;
    }
    n = firstrNum * powRec(firstrNum, secondNum - 1);
    printf("The result is %ld.", n);
}
int main()
{
    powRec(-2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

I wonder if the problem is in the printf or am I missing something?

Comment: `n` has type `int`, but the `%ld` expects a `long int`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the argument for printf that formats a long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561/what-is-the-argument-for-printf-that-formats-a-long)

Comment: @ShayHugi when you edit question you should improve it not break it. Your last edit made question unclear and detached from already submitted answer.

Comment: There's a bug in your code: you have an extra semicolon after the if statement which will cause the block after it to always execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message says, you are invoking *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to `printf()`.

`%ld` expects `long int`, but the passed `n` is `int`. You should use `%d` instead of that to print `int`.
Another choice is changing the type of `n` to `long int` to match with the format specifier.

Also note that:

- You should use indentation to make your code easier to read.
- The return type of `powRec` is `void`, so the line `n = firstrNum * powRec(firstrNum, secondNum - 1);` (especially the multiplication) is invalid.
- The semicolon in `if (secondNum == 1); {` may have your code behave differently from your expectation.